# Show popup to be confrim

Tags: netsuite

In sales order Accept and Reject button.when I'm  click the reject button it will show popup to confirm. Either i'm choosing ok button to reject and cancel button to stay that page.(In Workflow)

Any advice would be great, thanks

Comment: IT's just going to be standard JavaScript, as @k1komans shows in his answer.  Put it in a Client Script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the suitescript documentation.

```
if (confirm("Your alert message goes here")){
//positive action
}else{
//negative action
}
```